# Java: Self defined method parameter problems

Tags: java, methods, parameters, int

I'm trying to learn basic animation out of Lambert/Osborne's Fundamentals of Java. This method is defined within the Circle class, and taken right out of the book.

```
    public void move(){
    move((int)(velocity * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction))), (int)(velocity * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction))));
}
```

And I get the error:
Circle.java:49: move() in Circle cannot be applied to (int,int)
        move((int)(velocity * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(direction))), (int)(velocity * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(direction))));

I understand that it's a parameter problem, I just don't know how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you defined the other `move` method, the one that takes two parameters of type `int`? The `move` method is overloaded, and the two-parameter version must also be declared (in class `Circle` or a superclass of class `Circle`).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to do. Thanks for the quick, helpful response.